# How to test programs related to linked lists in Python

Tags: python, input, linked-list, tree, output

For example, merge 2 sorted linked lists.
I understand the code for solving the problem. However, how to create two linked lists and see the output? I have the same problem with trees. If I know how to test the input, it will be very helpful.

Input: `l1 = [1,2,4], l2 = [1,3,4]`
Output: `[1,1,2,3,4,4]`

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
```

Comment: So after you put [`python how to test programs`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+how+to+test+programs) into a search engine and looked at some of the results, was there something that still confused you? There are many ways to do this; deciding which is best is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As for how to create the lists, that depends on the entire linked-list definition, not just the node definition. (You can get away with just passing around the start nodes of the lists instead of having any kind of wrapper, but you still need to implement the list functionality in the nodes themselves in that case.) That said, I find it *extremely* dubious that you can figure out how to write code to merge two lists together, but not to create them in the first place - since the merging is a considerably harder task that involves all the same steps.

Comment: For questions related to arrays we can use the arrays directly as input. However, for linked lists, is there an easy way to convert the arrays to linked lists that can be used as input? And also print the output as an array. That is my question. I am a beginner. Hope I am not asking nonsense...

Comment: First off, you don't have "arrays"; we call them lists in Python. Second, how would you do it "the hard way"? Is it really that hard? I assume you know how to put a node into a list (since I can't imagine how you expect to merge the lists otherwise), and I assume you know how to repeat a task with each element of a list (since otherwise you are in *way* over your head).

Comment: @hehe the question in your comment is a different one from the actual question. I suggest spending sometime reading the archives. This has been answered many times. Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679759/how-to-generate-a-linked-list-from-a-standard-list-in-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987583/how-do-create-a-linked-list-in-python

Comment: Perhaps I was confused by what is provided by the questions. In the question, only node is defined and seems to be the input. I have to create another class for linked list in order to create linked list?

Comment: thanks a lot! I will look into them

Comment: Well, *what did your instructor say* about how to represent the list?

Comment: No you can do this all with the one class. It is sometimes convenient to use a different class to manage the list as a whole, but not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing solutions with linked lists it helps to have functions (or methods) which translate linked lists to lists and vice versa. So define these:

```
def to_linked_list(iterable):
    head = None
    for val in reversed(iterable):
        head = ListNode(val, head)
    return head

def to_native_list(head):
    lst = []
    while head:
        lst.append(head.val)
        head = head.next
    return lst
```

Now you can more easily test your solution:

```
l1 = to_linked_list([1,2,4])
l2 = to_linked_list([1,3,4])
result = Solution().mergeTwoLists(l1, l2)
print(to_native_list(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a test case: try something like this

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

l1 = ListNode(1)
l1.next = ListNode(2)
curr = l1.next
curr.next = ListNode(4)

l2 = ListNode(1)
l2.next = ListNode(3)
l2.next.next = ListNode(4)
```

I'll leave creating the solution list up to you.

Comment: thanks! I got it now. The links in the comment are also helpful.

Comment: Glad ListNode class is enough for testing purpose. I can do something similar for printing the solution